# Ensure phantomsection doesn't occur at the bottom of a page

Tags: hyperref

In my document I have boxes that cannot be broken across pages, and which therefore often leave blank space on the preceding pages. When I create a `\phantomsection` before one of these boxes, the `\phantomsection`/`\label` is left on the first page rather than being placed at the top of the new page. Is there a way to get it into the second page?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,hyperref}
\begin{document}
\hyperref[target]{My link}
\lipsum[1-4]
\phantomsection\label{target} % this stays on page 1
\vbox{\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add a `\clearpage` before `\phantomsection`

Comment: That would indeed work for this particular instance, but I would like a more general solution if possible. I don't want to have to recheck it every time the pagination changes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cause for the possible page break is the `\label` command that inserts a whatsit between the anchor and the box.

If I compile the following example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\hyperref[target]{My link}   

\phantomsection\label{target}\nopagebreak% this stays on page 1
\vbox{bbb}
\showoutput
\end{document}
```

the relevant part of the log file is

```
....\pdfdest name{section*.1} xyz
....\penalty 10000
....\write1{\newlabel{target}{{}{\thepage }{}{section*.1}{}}}
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\baselineskip) 3.11111
....\vbox(6.94444+0.0)x345.0
```

We see that an infinite penalty is added before the glue (that in your case will probably come from `\lineskip`, but this is irrelevant), thus inhibiting this glue to be used as page break point.

If the `\nopagebreak` is removed, we get

```
....\penalty 10000
....\write1{\newlabel{target}{{}{\thepage }{}{section*.1}{}}}
....\glue(\baselineskip) 3.11111
....\vbox(6.94444+0.0)x345.0
```

The whatsit (`\write1`) is not a discardable item, so the glue *can* be used as a page break point.

So

```
\phantomsection\label{target}\nopagebreak
```

should do.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,hyperref}
\begin{document}
\hyperref[target]{My link}
\lipsum[1-4]
\filbreak\phantomsection\label{target}\nopagebreak % 
\vbox{\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can put the `\phantomsection` inside the box to avoid that, i.e.

```
\vbox{\phantomsection\label{target}\lipsum[1]}
```

instead of

```
\phantomsection\label{target}
\vbox{\lipsum[1]}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,hyperref}
\begin{document}
\hyperref[target]{My link}
\lipsum[1-4]
\vbox{\phantomsection\label{target}\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

Now the link points to the right place.